# next.js app taking 15-25 seconds to load from "cold" on google app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, next.js

I am deploying a next.js app to a Google App Engine (standard) but I am having trouble with cold start times.

I am building locally then deploying the `.next` folder to GAE. On the first boot it takes 15-25 seconds to boot up. Looking at the logs I can see a log for a very long `GET 200` request but there's not really any information about what is going on. See image below:

[image]

When I run `yarn start` locally it boots up in < 1, which as far as I understand is running the same production build? It is almost as though GAE is doing a build before it eventually deploys..

Any pointers would be immensely appreciated!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was to enable the `serverless` in my next.js config.

Now it only takes 1 second to cold boot :)

Comment: Did you have to change something on google app engine or in the source code of your project? I have the same problem with the cold start but using "serverless" gives me errors during the build of the project. Thanks